# sql is not picking up duplicate dates

Tags: mysql, wordpress, date

I have a wordpress site where the dates are storing in this way 24/01/2014 under meta_value. If there are 2 dates with the same value then my sql is picking up only one date.

My query is :

```
SELECT wp_posts.* ,wp_postmeta.* 
       FROM wp_posts,wp_postmeta 
       WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
             AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
             AND wp_postmeta.meta_key='advert_date' 
             AND STR_TO_DATE(wp_postmeta.meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31' 
      GROUP BY wp_postmeta.meta_value 
      ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value asc
```

There are total 7 records and the dates are

```
1 -- 03/01/2014

2 -- 08/01/2014

3 -- 10/01/2014

4 -- 16/01/2014

5 -- 24/01/2014

6 -- 24/01/2014

7 -- 31/01/2014
```

Whereas it is showing only 6 records and ignoring record id 6.

Is it ignoring the duplicate records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `group by wp_postmeta.meta_value` from your SQL.

Answer (score 2):

group by statement in mysql combines entries that are duplicates. It's very handy. Since you have grouped by the date, it will 'aggregate' all dates in common. However only the first one is shown that was grouped by. This is typically useful when using an aggregate function like SUM or AVERAGE. Say you want to know all the money made on a date. Group by the date and SUM up the money. YOu will get an entry for each date and how much money.